# How do I transfer data from the terminal to Microsoft Excel?

Tags: terminal, process, microsoft-excel

I generated data in the terminal from running a python game, and I would like to automatically have the data go into an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest methods to use to move data into Excel or another spreadsheet from text output is by using the CSV or character delimited data options.  If you are able to format the output of the python game into CSV or character delimited values then you can use Excel to open this output and a wizard will allow you to select options on how to import the data.